# How to hide real world in an ARScene

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

Hello I want to show only the 3d objects that I add in my ARSCNView and not showing everything else like the room like walls etc. Is there any configuration in ARSCNView that does that? For example showing my objects and all the other space to be white...

Comment: and will it project the nodes based on the move of my phone?

Comment: So what you want is to hide the video feed and only show the 3D aspects? Basically, you want to create VR with ARKit?

Comment: @SilentK yes but have in mind that this might change so I need to use ARScene. I think about creating a big sphere and be inside of it but I need a more elegant solution